# jQuery html5 localStorage removeItem error

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

Here in this code:

```
$('#doneItem').click(function(){
        $(this).each(function(index){
            var item = 'personal' + index;
            alert(item);
            localStorage.removeItem('personal' + index);
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
});
```

#doneItem is a button, and i want to remove the 'personal0' for ex. from localStorage and...
Uncaght TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeItem' of undefined.   Any ideas??

Comment: Are you sure every item `'personal' + index` is in the localStorage?

Comment: When you alert out item are you getting the entry you were hoping for? Have you seen tried replacing ('personal' + index) with just your item variable just to see what happens? Niklas also has a very good point. If it is going through for .each() and it finds one that is not in the localStorage you will get that error as well. It will delete the ones it has found but error when it reaches one it can't Have you checked the console?

Comment: I tried to replace, but same result, and yes the alert is to check is this the right result that i want. In the console: 78event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. 
script.js:33Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeItem' of undefined

Comment: Does your browser support localStorage? Or are you working on incognito mode?

Comment: Can be a problem that other content (#doneItem) is dynamically created by js?

Comment: Well, you should never have two elements with the same id.

Comment: If i try with class? Or dynamic id i mean -> #doneItem1, #doneItem2.. 
but after that how to access all theese different buttons with one function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check if the item is in the localStorage before trying to remove it?

```
if (item in localStorage) localStorage.removeItem(item);
```

I assume you've checked that the browser uses localStorage?

**EDIT**
You can try to use a dynamic id. This will match all `a` elements that start with `doneItem` and then get the number at the end to the `index` variable.

```
    $("a[id^=doneItem]").click(function(){
            var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("doneItem", "");                
            var item = 'personal' + index;
            localStorage.removeItem(item);
            window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

You would also need to change this line and insert an `i` there:

```
document.write("<a data-role=\"button\" id=\"doneItem" + i + "\" data-transition=\"none\" href=\"#showPersonal\" data-icon=\"check\" data-iconpos=\"left\">Done</a>");
```

This will only work if you comment out the Modernizr code too. You're replacing the localstorage variable here, and I don't know why you do that.

```
    /*   
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
          var localStorage = window.storage;
    } else {
          alert('Your browser does not support local storage!');
    }
    */
```

These problem might only be with **jsfiddle** so I had to remove some more code, but here's a somewhat working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zr4tg/53/

It might not look like you want but it should be working. Let me know =)

Comment: The item is in the localStorage 100%, and browser supports html5 localStorage. But the error appears evan if i write something like this: `localStorage.removeItem('personal0');` (exact key) and dafuq..

Comment: Could you explain again why you are using each here? I'm reading it like this: for each `#doneItem` element, remove an index from localStorage. But there can only be one `#doneItem`. Also, why are you applying this function to the `#doneItem` if you aren't using any information from it? The code inside the each function could just as well be outside it and still work?

Comment: for each #doneItem element (there are created many dynamically with js for loop from localStorage's data) get the index of the #doneItem and concatenate it like this: ("personal" + index) which for ex. is "personal0" that is a key in localStorage and i want to remove element with that key and then refresh the page to show the results

Comment: Tricky one =) Would you be able to reproduce the problem in http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zr4tg/4/   but u shoulda copy the js section in js/script.js   and i think u will can try it

Comment: and if i try these two lines code (to getItem) its gives me same error but for method getItem....

Comment: and about the modernizr i dont know ... :D

Comment: and can i only ask you to explain this selector : `$("a[id^=doneItem]")` , what is **^=** doing?

Comment: It says to match all `a` elements having an `id` that starts with `^=` the string `doneItem`. Here's some more info on this: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: 10x, and can i for example if i have: `id=doneItem0Personal` to get that `personal` in other variable called `section`  ?

Comment: i made it! thanks again and here is the code `$("a[id^=doneItem]").click(function(){
            var index = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
            var section = $(this).attr("id").replace(/doneItem[0-9]/g , "");              
            var item = section + index;
            localStorage.removeItem(item);
            window.location.reload(true);
     });  `